# Zooming in highchart makes line disappear

Tags: android, highcharts, android-webview

I'm using highchart in an android app to display a dynamic chart that is updated every 3 secs and displayed over one day.

My chart is composed of two fixed data series displaying the limit that the monitored data should not exceed, and obviously the monitored data (power value)
All the power value from 00:05 to the moment the chart is loaded, are first displayed. And then, every 3 seconds, a value is added to this serie.

The problem is when I try to zoom to the end point of my power values. The power data line (and only this one) disappear when I zoom in. If I zoom out, the line reappears. But if I zoom on an area where the end point of my data power line is not displayed, everything goes right.

I tried to remove the two fixed serie (it adjust my chart height to the length of the power data line but whatever), and the same zoom problem appears. I can't zoom to the end point of my power data line but I can zoom anywhere else.
I also tried to use datagrouping, but the problem stay the same

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
 $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: true
            }
        });

var dataPower = Android.getDayHistory((new Date()).getHours(), (new Date()).getMinutes(), (new Date()).getSeconds());
//var dataPower = [];
console.log(dataPower);

// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts(
        'StockChart',
        {

            chart : {
                type : 'line',
                backgroundColor : '#d6d7d4',
                ignoreHiddenSeries: false, 
                zoomType : 'x',

                marginRight : 10,
                events : {
                    load : function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];

                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Android.getData((new Date()).getHours(),(new Date()).getMinutes(), (new Date()).getSeconds());
                            series.addPoint([ x, y ]);

                            Android.checkAlert((new Date()).getHours(),(new Date()).getMinutes(), (new Date()).getSeconds());
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                },
            },

            rangeSelector : {
                buttons : [ {
                    type : 'minute',
                    count : 2,
                    text : '2m'
                }, {
                    type : 'minute',
                    count : 5,
                    text : '5m'
                }, {
                    type : 'minute',
                    count : 30,
                    text : '30m'
                }, {
                    type : 'hour',
                    count : 1,
                    text : '1h'
                }, {
                    type : 'all',
                    text : 'All'
                } ],
                selected : 4,
                inputEnabled : false,
            },

            xAxis : {
                ordinal : false,
                minRange : 36000
            },

            yAxis : {
                title : {
                    text : 'Power (MW)'
                },
                max : 500,
                plotBands : [ {
                    from : 0,
                    to : 100,
                    color : 'rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.3)'
                }, {
                    from : 100,
                    to : 200,
                    color : 'rgba(215, 216, 212, 0.3)'
                }, { // Light breeze
                    from : 200,
                    to : 300,
                    color : 'rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.3)'
                }, { // Light breeze
                    from : 300,
                    to : 400,
                    color : 'rgba(215, 216, 212, 0.3)'
                }, {
                    from : 400,
                    to : 500,
                    color : 'rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.3)'
                } ]
            },

            plotOptions: {
                spline: {
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            lineWidth: 3
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled : true,
                                radius: 5,
                                lineWidth: 1
                            }
                        }  
                    }      
                }
            },


            title : {},

            subtitle : {},

            navigator : {
                enabled : false

            },
            scrollbar : {
                enabled : false
            },

            credits : {
                enabled : false
            },

            series : [
                    {
                        name : 'Power',
                        data : eval('[' + dataPower + ']'),
                        pointStart : Date.UTC((new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                (new Date()).getMonth(), (new Date()).getDate()),
                        pointInterval : 3000,

                    },
                    {
                        data : [
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 0,
                                                5, 0), 40 ],
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 7,
                                                0, 0), 40 ],
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 7,
                                                30, 0), 440 ],
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 11,
                                                57, 0), 440 ],
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 12,
                                                3, 0), 390 ],
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 13,
                                                57, 0), 390 ]
                                ,
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 14,
                                                3, 0), 440 ],
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 17,
                                                3, 0), 440 ],
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 23,
                                                55, 0), 40 ] 
                                                ],
                        type : 'line',
                        color : "#d3a6ad",
                        enableMouseTracking : false
                    },
                    {
                        data : [
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 0,
                                                5, 0), 60 ],
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 7,
                                                0, 0), 60 ],
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 7,
                                                30, 0), 460 ],
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 11,
                                                57, 0), 460 ],
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 12,
                                                3, 0), 410 ],
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 13,
                                                57, 0), 410 ]
                                ,
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 14,
                                                3, 0), 460 ],
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 17,
                                                3, 0), 460 ],
                                [
                                        Date.UTC(
                                                (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                                                (new Date()).getMonth(),
                                                (new Date()).getDate(), 23,
                                                55, 0), 60 ]
                                ],
                        type : 'line',
                        color : "#d3a6ad",
                            enableMouseTracking : false
                    } ]

        });
 });
});
```